# ARM - Template - Multiple References

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

How can I achieve the following please:

1. Setup Key Vault
2. Setup Web App
3. Enable MSI
4. Reference Key vault to  get secret URLs
5. Assign MSI Identity with Key vault Access policies

I have managed to complete till 4 but I cannot seem to find a way how I can re use key vault to assign the MSI ID with Access policies. To clarify I know how to set access policies in ARM, what I am not managing is using the same Key vault twice in the arm template.

Has anyone managed to re-reference resources?

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667050/azure-keyvault-add-function-msi-via-arm already?

Comment: This is not related in anyway to my question. I need to assign MSI Identity to Vault after both Vault and WebApp have been created.

Comment: accesspolicies is an array in the template under keyvault . so you can configure multiple access policies for different applicationIDs

Comment: The issue is not adding access policies, but the order and duplicate reference restrictions. Please re read my question maybe you have misunderstood.

Comment: Could you post your ARM template please ? At least the parts relative to keyvaul and azure web app ?