# App Service Key Vault Reference breaks when re-deploying ARM template

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-webapps

I have an Azure App Service Web App using Key Vault References for several application settings. All resources are deployed and configured through an Bicep/ARM template. The secrets in Key Vault and Access Policies are set through the Bicep/ARM template as well. The Web App works great and has access to Key Vault through those references until I re-deploy the Bicep / ARM template to modify some unrelated values. After running "az deployment group create" the references break (showing red cross in application settings). I found two workarounds to make them connect again:

- Restart Web App
- Create another app setting / modify a setting in the portal and save

I would like to understand the root cause / possible mistake and why the work-arrounds help. I checked, and the Secrets in Key Vault are not changed / updated when re-deploying the template. My assumption is that this is caused by the Key Vault API removing and re-creating the Access Policies each time the template gets deployed. A what-if deployment of the template tells me that the removal and re-creation of the Access Policies is happening.

Comment: ARM does not allow a key vault to be redeployed without clearing its existing access policies. The `accessPolicies` property is required, omitting it will cause an error. Setting it to `[]` will clear all existing policies. You can refer to [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67850177/15969115) and  [Microsoft feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906355-azure-key-vault/suggestions/34414747-arm-template-for-keyvault-to-have-accesspolicies-n).

Comment: I asked the PG about this: it is by-design of ARM templates.  I don't know the technical reasons behind it.

I posted about this here a few years ago. 

https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2018/05/29/azure-key-vault-access-policy-update-via-arm-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Deepdave in the comment section. ARM does not allow a key vault to be redeployed with out clearing existing access polices.

Please submit your feedback here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback